# How can I access what a function was called on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am assuming that `$('thing1')` or `document.getElementById('thing1')` will return the node or object representing `<div id="thing1"></div>` But how do I access that in `myFunc()`?

HTML:

```
<div id="thing1"></div>
```

JS:

```
var foo = $('#thing1').myFunc();

var myFunc = function() {
    console.log(this);         // I want to log $('#thing1')
}
```

I am trying to figure out how various api's work, take highcharts for example, they do something like this:

```
$('#dailyKPIChart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        spacingRight: 20
    }
});
```

And the chart will load in `$('#dailyKPIChart')`

How does that work?

Comment: Did you create a jQuery plugin?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, this code is going to result in an error.

Comment: `var foo = $('#thing1').myFunc();` that makes no sense. myFunc is not defined as a method of `$('#thing1')`. How do you expect to call it?

Comment: @ComFreek, so I don't really know what I was doing, but I am trying to figure out how some apis work the way I outlined in my update to the question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to (programatically) know which variable (or which function call) was used to get the object upon which a method was called.

A debugger will tell you (set a break point, and then look at the stack) but that won't be useful if you think you need to know the name in your code.

`$a_jquery_object.selector` will (in older versions of jQuery) hold the selector used to construct a jQuery object, which might help for your particular example.

---

> And the chart will load in `$('#dailyKPIChart')`
>
> How does that work?

It doesn't need to know about `$()` or `'#dailyKPIChart'`, it only needs the object that you get when calling it, which is available through `this`, which your earlier example code already uses.

Comment: `.selector` was removed in 1.9 (just saying)

Comment: But how do you aviod Object [object Object] has no method 'myFunc' ?

Comment: @Ian it was never removed http://jsfiddle.net/7bXSS/, but once the jQuery object is in state where .selector doesn't make sense, the property is deleted whereas before there was a bunch of meaningless `findAll()` etc in the string.

Comment: @Esailija Hmm definitely wouldn't have expected that from http://api.jquery.com/selector/ . Yeah it looks like `selector` stays there for simple/minimal filtering

Comment: @sherlock — *boggle* - Are you asking about how to put a method on an object or how to add a method on all jQuery objects?

Comment: Prob. how to put a method on an object, but i think i got it from Icarus's answer. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to invoke a function in javascript and perhaps you are after `call` (or its cousin `apply`):

Supposing you define your funciton as:

```
var myFunc = function() {
    console.log(this);         // I want to log $('#thing1')
}
```

You can call it while at the same time you specify the `context`. For example, you can do this:

```
var foo = $('#thing1');

var myFunc = function() {
    console.log(this);      
}
myFunc.apply(foo);
```

Or via `call`:

```
var foo = $('#thing1');

var myFunc = function() {
    console.log(this);      
}
myFunc.call(foo);
```

If you have arguments to pass, you can do so by specifying an argument list or an array of arguments. For example:

```
var foo = $('#thing1');


var myFunc = function(one, two) {
    console.log(one);
    console.log(two);
    console.log(this);         
}
myFunc.apply(foo,[2,3]);
```

Or with call:

```
myFunc.apply(foo,2,3); //foo is the calling context
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAxPb/)